# named.confの設定項目について(bind9)

Tags: centos, dns

現在bind9の設定をしようとしています。
named.confのoption項目として設定するforwardersと、type hintを指定した時に
参照先として記載するファイルについてよく理解できておらず。。
それぞれの役割についてご説明できる方、ご教示ください。

この質問で不明な点あればご指摘くだされば補足いたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

optionsでforwardersが指定されている場合、まずforwardersに問い合わせます。ここで解決できない場合、

```
zone "." { type hint; };
```

なエントリがあれば、hintファイルを参照してルートサーバからの名前解決を試みます。

optionsで`forward only`を指定すると、forwardersに問い合わせて失敗した時点でクライアントに失敗の応答をします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。なるほど・・そういう挙動をするのですね。諸事情で検証できる環境がなく、ググっても理解がまとまらなかったのでご質問させていただきました。fowardersはキャッシュサーバからキャッシュサーバへ、という感じなんですね。確かにそれのほうがリカージョンするよりは早く解決できそうです。